# Angular-CLI not creating all the default component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-cli

creating a new module using angular-cli it generate only the xx.module.ts
How how to generate the rest of the default files like
    module1.component.ts
    module1.component.html
    module1.component.css`enter code here`

please help

Comment: What version of *Angular-cli* do you use? It should generate module along with a template, component, styles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With the current iteration to generate a component with a module you need to use the `--routing` flag.

Please know that the generation of the component may be going away even when using this flag. This will give you greater control when generating the associated component that you do not have when the module creates it.